# When parsing datetime into month day with English culture, it is still parsed in Turkish language

Tags: c#, string, datetime, string-formatting, culture

Here is the code. I still get incorrect results

```
string srRegisterDate = "25.07.2009 00:00:00"
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
srRegisterDate = String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate), culture);
```

The result is `Cumartesi, Temmuz 25, 2009`

Instead it should be `Saturday, July 25, 2009`

How can i fix this error?

C#.net v4.5.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because of **ignored** culture value in `String.Format` and not with converting string to `DateTime`.

You need:

```
srRegisterDate = String.Format(culture, "{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate));
```

Your current call to `String.Format` utalizes the overload [`String.Format Method (String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) and the `culture` passed in parameter is treated as a simple object parameter passed for place holder. Since there is no place holder, you don't even see it getting ignored.

If you want to have `culture` utilized in `String.Format` then you have to use the overload : `Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object)` or `String.Format Method (IFormatProvider, String, Object[])`

Answer (score 7):

`Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate)` *still* uses your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which looks like `tr-TR` based on day and month names. [Cumartesi](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumartesi) - [Temmuz](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temmuz)

In `String.Format`, your culture will be ignored since you used it as a third parameter as an argument but you never use it.

Your code called [`Format(string format, object arg0, object arg1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf3d0ccc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload. But you never use the `arg1`. This overload doesn't think this is a culture. It thinks it is *another* argument that you want to format.

This `String.Format` has an overloads that takes `IFormatProvider` as a **first** argument.

- [`Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[]`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object, Object`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906223%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object, Object, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906221%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example;

```
srRegisterDate = String.Format(culture, "{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate));
```

But most comman way (and I always prefer) to get the result that you want is using `.ToString()` method like;

```
srRegisterDate = Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate).ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy", culture);
```

Comment: No that is not the issue, issue is converting `DateTime` to string. String.Format is ignoring culture parameter.

Comment: @Habib Fool me. Thanks. Now it looks like your solution :(

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
DateTimeFormatInfo trDtfi = new CultureInfo("tr-TR", false).DateTimeFormat;
string result = String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate, trDtfi).ToString(usDtfi));
```

original

25.07.2009 00:00:00

transformed

7/25/2009 12:00:00 AM

**EDIT**

Was one to short of required

```
string test = String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate, trDtfi).ToString(usDtfi)));
```

Saturday, July 25, 2009

Comment: This is not what OP wants.

Comment: yes that will work, but there is **another issue** with this. There is **no need of `String.Format`**, your format will be ignored since you are **passing a string parameter and not a `DateTime`** parameter. Consider the example `string result = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate, trDtfi).ToString(usDtfi));` with your code,

Comment: Yeah I noticed was to happy to solve the culture transform .. sry OP

Comment: Again, with your EDIT `string test = String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(srRegisterDate, trDtfi).ToString(usDtfi)));
` , you are converting, string to DateTime, and then Converting it to string and then again converting it to DateTime to pass to `String.Format`, do you see the issue with that ?

Comment: Obviously I don't so enlighten me, I don't mind losing rep, I want to know the best way.  The end result gives what the OP expected though